# WordPress post_exists returning wrong value (timeout issue?)

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a client with a WordPress site who's not very tech savvy and doesn't want to update the site herself. There's a page on the site that syndicates her own content from her employer's blog. Her employer's site doesn't have an RSS feed, but I was able to set up a simple script with [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape the content to be syndicated and create a new WordPress post for each new entry found on her employer's site. I'm doing this with a cron job once a week, which is as often as she writes new content for her employer's site.

The problem I'm having is that when my cron script takes longer than 30 seconds to execute, WordPress's `post_exists` function fails to find the first entry entry I search for, and a duplicate post is created.

Following is the code for the cron script. For the sake of my client's privacy, I'm replacing any identifiable information with a `[[placeholder]]`.

```
<?php
require( 'wp-load.php' );
if ( !function_exists( 'post_exists' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}
require( 'simple_html_dom.php' );

update_bac();

function update_bac()
{
    // log each cron execution for easier troubleshooting in the event of issues
    $logfile = 'bac_cron.log';
    file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  \n", FILE_APPEND );
    file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Cron executed\n", FILE_APPEND );

    // Set a long time limit to avoid cron timeouts
    $time_limit_success = (set_time_limit( 900 )) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  set_time_limit successful? {$time_limit_success} \n", FILE_APPEND );
```

Removed here is the code that does the actual scraping. It works, and constructs an array, `$entries_to_post`, where each item is an array of post data with a post title (`'name'`), a published date in "Y-m-d H:i:s" format (`'date'`), a link to the post on the employer's website (`'href'`), and an image src (`'img'`).

```
    // create a WordPress post for each entry in the array that doesn't already exist in the database
    foreach( $entries_to_post as $postdata )
    {
        file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Looping entries_to_post, found {$postdata['name']}, {$postdata['date']} \n", FILE_APPEND );

        $matching_post_id = post_exists( $postdata['name'], '', $postdata['date'] );
```

According to WordPress's docs, `post_exists` should return a post ID in the event of a hit, or 0 if no such post exists. The first argument is the post title, second argument is the post content (all of the posts have empty content, because I'm using custom fields for all of the relevant data), third argument is the publish date.

```
        if( $matching_post_id === 0 )
        {
            file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Match not found in database, adding new post... \n", FILE_APPEND );

            $postarr = [
                'post_author' => 0,
                'post_date' => $postdata['date'],
                'post_title' => $postdata['name'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => '[[custom-post-type]]'
            ];
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $postarr, true );

            if( is_int( $post_id ) )
            {
                update_field( 'field_5741032e15daf', $postdata['href'], $post_id );
                update_field( 'field_5b93201831b5d', $postdata['img'], $post_id );
```

`update_field` is an Advanced Custom Fields function; I'm using it here to update the necessary custom fields after the post is created.

```
                file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Post created: " . $post_id . ", " . $postdata['name'] . ", " . $postdata['href'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
            }
            // wp_insert_post returns a WP_Error instead of a post ID if it fails
            else if( is_wp_error( $post_id ) )
            {
                file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Something went wrong!\n", FILE_APPEND );
                file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  " . $post_id->get_error_message(), FILE_APPEND );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Matching post found with ID {$matching_post_id} \n", FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }

    file_put_contents( $logfile, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) . "  Reached end of array\n", FILE_APPEND );
}
```

If the cron takes less than 30 seconds to execute, it works as expected, and if there are no new entries, this is what the log file looks like:

```
2018-09-21 17:36:03  
2018-09-21 17:36:03  Cron executed
2018-09-21 17:36:03  set_time_limit successful? TRUE 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-1]], 2018-06-08 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Matching post found with ID 516 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-2]], 2018-07-12 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Matching post found with ID 475 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-3]], 2018-08-31 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Matching post found with ID 476 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-4]], 2018-08-17 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Matching post found with ID 477 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-5]], 2018-09-07 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Matching post found with ID 478
...
2018-09-21 17:36:24  Reached end of array
```

If it takes LONGER than 30 seconds to execute, this is what the log looks like:

```
2018-09-21 16:53:27  
2018-09-21 16:53:27  Cron executed
2018-09-21 16:53:27  set_time_limit successful? TRUE 
2018-09-21 16:54:27  
2018-09-21 16:54:27  Cron executed
2018-09-21 16:54:27  set_time_limit successful? TRUE 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-1]], 2018-06-08 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Matching post found with ID 516 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-2]], 2018-07-12 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Matching post found with ID 475 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-3]], 2018-08-31 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Matching post found with ID 476 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-4]], 2018-08-17 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Matching post found with ID 477 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-5]], 2018-09-07 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Matching post found with ID 478
...
2018-09-21 16:55:01  Reached end of array
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-1]], 2018-06-08 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Match not found in database, adding new post... 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Post created: 526, [[post-title-1]], [[href]]
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-2]], 2018-07-12 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Matching post found with ID 475 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-3]], 2018-08-31 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Matching post found with ID 476 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-4]], 2018-08-17 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Matching post found with ID 477 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Looping entries_to_post, found [[post-title-5]], 2018-09-07 00:00:00 
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Matching post found with ID 478 
...
2018-09-21 16:55:02  Reached end of array
```

The `...`s are just a bunch of additional loop iterations, about 40 in total — I've truncated the log for brevity.

As you can see, if it takes longer than 30 seconds, the cron executes twice. The second execution happens exactly one minute after the first, but for some reason it immediately loops through the array twice on the second execution, and on one of those loops (sometimes it's the first loop, sometimes it's the second), the first item in the array is not found with `post_exists` and a duplicate post is created.

Things I've tried:

- I changed `if( !post_exists(...) )` to `if( post_exists(...) === 0 )` to make sure I'm actually getting 0 and not something else. No effect.
- I added `set_time_limit( 900 )` to the top of the script (and logged it to make sure it worked) to make sure the cron script has plenty of time to execute.
- I added a .user.ini with `max_execution_time = 120` and `error_log = /home/[[user]]/html/php_error.log`. I hoped that increasing the max execution time globally might help, in case it was the `post_exists` function or something else that was timing out, but it doesn't seem to have had any effect. (The client is on a Managed WordPress plan with GoDaddy, so my options for server configuration and access are a little limited. The .user.ini file is how GoDaddy says to do PHP configurations, and it's supposed to check the file every 5 minutes.)
- I added more log statements to see exactly what was happening, which helped me narrow down the problem, but I still don't know how to actually fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Those 30 seconds looks a lot like the default php execution time to me.

I dont know about the internals of wordpress cron, but I could Imagine that it just starts the job again if it failed for example by running into max_execution_time.

You could double-check if the execution-time was set correctly by adding

```
ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

to your logfile or even add a shutdown-handler to see if the program aborts for any other reason:

```
register_shutdown_function( 
 function(){ 
     echo "Shutdown.".print_r(error_get_last(),true);
 });
```

It could be something about concurrency. You could check for that by adding some random string to your log-message that you generate once per request (or however those cronjobs are triggered).

**In General:**

If you run into limits of execution-times (be it by configuration or other limits on other resources) you could always try to split your problem into smaller chunks.

For example, you could run your scraper, serialize the output to some temporary file and load that file in another task that just has to read this file.

If this is not enough, you could split your problems further (i.E. make the scraper resumable or aware of already visited content, so it just has to parse part of the data).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just to clarify, this isn't using WordPress cron (that's only executed when someone visits the site). I actually had to use cron-job.org to set up a custom cron job because of GoDaddy's limitations. I think splitting the task into two separate jobs might do the trick.

Comment: if you happen to find out the reason for this strange behaviour please let me know!